# Find $f(5)$, if the graph of the quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ intersects the ordinate axis at point $(0;3)$ and its vertex is at point $(2;0)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $f(5)$, if the graph of the quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ intersects the ordinate axis at point $(0;3)$ and its vertex is at point $(2;0)$

So I used the vertex form, $y=(x-2)^2+3$, got the quadratic equation and then put $5$ instead of $x$ to get the answer, but it's wrong. I think I shouldn't have added $3$ in the vertex form but I don't know how else I can solve this

Comment: When you take your "vertex form" and plug in $x = 0$, do you get $y = 3$? I don't. But you've been told that $(0, 3)$ is on the graph. So perhaps you misused the vertex form... (By the way, the point $(2, 0)$ isn't on your graph either!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that one solution is to use the vertex form

$$y=a(x-h)^2+k$$

but you have $k$ wrong. If the vertex is at $(2,0)$ then $h=2$ (which you have) and $k=0$ (which you got wrong). So the equation is now

$$y=a(x-2)^2+0$$
or
$$y=a(x-2)^2$$

Now use the fact that $(0,3)$ is on the parabola, so $x=0,y=3$ satisfies the equation:

$$3=a(0-2)^2$$

So $a=\frac 34$. Thus the full equation is

$$y=\frac 34(x-2)^2$$

Finally, we want the value of $y$ when $x=5$, which is

$$y=\frac 34(5-2)^2$$
or
$$y=\frac{27}4$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints: Plug $x=0$ into $ax^2+bx+c=3$ to find the value of $c$. Then note that the vertex of a parabola is at $x$-coordinate $-\frac{b}{2a}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I got $c=3$ and $b=-4a$, still can't get the right answer though

Answer (score 0):

Intersect the ordinate in $(0;3)$ implies: $$3=f(0)=a0^2+b0+c=c$$ 
If you use $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$, with $x$ the vertex, you get 
$$2=-b/2a \implies b=-4a$$
Evolve $f(2)=0$ 
using the equation of the form given in the problem, then you will have
$$0=a2^2+b2+3 \implies 2b=-3-4a = -a+b \implies b=-3$$
So, $$-3=-4a \implies a=\frac{3}{4}$$ 
Then,
$$f(x)=\frac{3}{4}x^2-3x+2$$
$$f(5)=\frac{75}{4}-15+3=\frac{27}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

As we know:
$2ax + b=0$ when $x=2$

This means $4a + b=0$ or $b=-4a$

Now you can substitute

$a×2^2 - 4a×2 +3=0$

Or $4a - 8a +3=0$

Or $a=\frac{3}{4}$

Now you can get $b$ and you can get $f(5)$